# If there is possibility to add comments to C++ code in VS Code that are displayed in IntelliSense window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I use Visual Studio Code for nearly half a year, and I actually wonder if in Visual Studio Code there is possibility of adding comments to C++ code that can be viewed while IntelliSense window for function is vieved.

Something like this, but in C++:
[Sample for other language](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/editor/intellisense/intellisense_docs.gif)

Do you know if it is possible and how it can be reached? What should be comment convention to have above effect?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Did You solved this? I'm looking for same functionality combined with platformio. Thanks for hint!

Comment: @Misiu Actually it simply works, I think that it was implemented in some update :) I have `C/C++`, `C++ Intellisense` addons with C++ in name. Settings: "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default". Comment style which I tested is `// comment`. I tested it with functions.

Comment: Thanks for quick update. I've tried yesterday to comment my code a bit, but nothing showed up in intellisense. I'll try that today and hopefully it will work fine. P.S. I found issue in VS Code https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/399 and it looks like this isn't fully supported. Can You post an answer to Your question? With VS Code version, addons list and config settings? This would help not only me :)

Comment: @Misiu Of course, I will provide answer with that informations

Comment: Hopefully MS will support full XML comments soon.
Dzięki!

Comment: Hello @BartekPL can you update the link in your question or insert a figure please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Done ;)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as I and @Misiu checked, there isn't fully support of this feature.

But partial support of this functionality is provided in VS Code.

For clarity I list partial information about my computer and editor:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- VS Code version: Code 1.20.1 (f88bbf9137d24d36d968ea6b2911786bfe103002, 2018-02-13T15:31:21.019Z)
- OS version: Linux x64 4.4.0-116-generic
- Extension(**only connected with cpp**) | Author (truncated) | Version

  - **code-gnu-global** | aus | 0.2.2
  - **cpptools** | ms- | 0.15.0
- The only one setting connected with this addons:

  - `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default"`

Sample of how it works:

[image]