# How to get Clion like function description in VS code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, documentation

Intellisense description:

[image: img]

IntelliJ description:

[image: Img]

The Intellisense description in vscode is too short and not much descriptive. Is there any way (like some extension) to get CLion like description in vscode?

Comment: Clion headers probably have doxygen comments and those you use in VS no

Comment: I do not think VScode is able to detect the doxygen comments even with the C/C++ extenions. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49151058/14501343

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73326790/11107541